# string to date in Python (00Z 26 Feb 1983 to 00-26-02-83)

Tags: python, string, datetime, text-files, extract

I have a text file on which I need to fine the lines which contain dates ( e.g  00Z 26 Feb) want to extract the date from a string which looks like:

```
<H2>04018 BIKF Keflavikurflugvollur Observations at 00Z 26 Feb 1983</H2>
<H2>04018 BIKF Keflavikurflugvollur Observations at 12Z 26 Feb 1983</H2>
<H2>04018 BIKF Keflavikurflugvollur Observations at 00Z 28 Feb 1983</H2>
<H2>04018 BIKF Keflavikurflugvollur Observations at 12Z 28 Feb 1983</H2>
```

and so on.

So I want to find the line where a date is contained and then extract 00Z 26 Feb 1983 and transform it into 00-26-02-1983. How is it possible to do that in Python ? 
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Iona, please edit your question to let us know what you have already tried and why it didn't work

Comment: Hi, I m quite new to Python and I tried to google how to do this and came across datetime. I tried datetime_object = datetime.strptime('00Z 28 Feb 1983', '%h %d %M %Y') but it didn t work.

Comment: do you want to actually reprint the whole line with the date substituted or do you just want to print the date?

Comment: You can [edit] and add your attempt to your question. Also include more details that the basic "It didn't work".

Comment: to just print the dates, not all the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a simpler route but this works (from one of your lines):

```
from time import strptime
text = "<H2>04018 BIKF Keflavikurflugvollur Observations at 00Z 26 Feb 1983</H2>"
text = text.replace("Z","").replace("</H2>","").split(" ")
text[-2]=str(strptime(text[-2],"%b").tm_mon)
text = "-".join(text[-4:])
```

gives:

```
print(text)
> '00-26-2-1983'
```

---

**Explanations:**

`text.replace("Z","")` removes "Z" in your text (replaces "Z" by empty string ""). `.replace("</H2>","")` further removes "". `.split(" ")` changes your string into a list of string. This 3rd line then returns:

```
['<H2>04018', 'BIKF', 'Keflavikurflugvollur', 'Observations', 'at', '00', '26', 'Feb', '1983']
```

Here we just need to change "Feb" (index `-2` as it appears in second last in our list) to a number which is done with `strptime(text[-2],"%b").tm_mon` and convert it back to a string with `str()`. This 4th line then returns:

```
['<H2>04018', 'BIKF', 'Keflavikurflugvollur', 'Observations', 'at', '00', '26', '2', '1983']
```

Finally, the strings of interest (from index `-4` to the end) can be joined with "-" as you requested, as is done in the last line `"-".join(text[-4:])`.

---

Also there are several problems with what you already tried `datetime_object = datetime.strptime('00Z 28 Feb 1983', '%h %d %M %Y')`. First, strptime doesn't know what it should do with "Z": you have to discard it before giving it to the function. Then, you do not pass the correct arguments to your function. According to [the tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm), here is what you tell strptime:

- `%h` : same as `%b` = abbreviated month name
- `%d` : day of the month (01 to 31)
- `%M` : minute
- `%Y` : year including the century

But these are not what you are actually giving to the function: '00 28 Feb 1983' is in fact:

- `%H` : hour, using a 24-hour clock (00 to 23)
- `%d` : day of the month (01 to 31) (this one was correct)
- `%b` : abbreviated month name
- `%Y` : year including the century (this one was correct)

Fixing this, you get:

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('00 28 Feb 1983', '%H %d %b %Y')
>  time.struct_time(tm_year=1983, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=28, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=59, tm_isdst=-1)
```

From which you can get:

```
text = str(datetime_object.tm_hour)+"-"+str(datetime_object.tm_mday)+"-"+str(datetime_object.tm_mon)+"-"+str(datetime_object.tm_year)
> '0-28-2-1983'
```

Answer (score 1):

use `regex` and `datetime` together

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

line = '<H2>04018 BIKF Keflavikurflugvollur Observations at 00Z 26 Feb 1983</H2>'
matches = re.findall(r"(\d{2}Z \d{2} [a-zA-Z]{3} \d{4})", line)
for match in matches:
    line = line.replace(match, datetime.strptime(match, '%HZ %d %b %Y').strftime('%H-%d-%m-%Y'))
print(line)
```

another option is use `re.sub` directly as follows

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

def my_replace(match):
    match = match.group()
    return datetime.strptime(match, '%HZ %d %b %Y').strftime('%H-%d-%m-%Y')

line = '<H2>04018 BIKF Keflavikurflugvollur Observations at 00Z 26 Feb 1983</H2>'
line = re.sub(r"(\d{2}Z \d{2} [a-zA-Z]{3} \d{4})", my_replace, line)
print(line)
```

output is

```
    <H2>04018 BIKF Keflavikurflugvollur Observations at 00-26-02-1983</H2>
```

Comment: the `extract 00Z 26 Feb 1983` in the original question makes me think only the final date is requested here

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

string = '<H2>04018 BIKF Keflavikurflugvollur Observations at 00Z 26 Feb 1983</H2>'
string = string.replace('<H2>', '')
string = string.replace('</H2>', '')
splitted_string = string.split('at ')
#  ex:['04018 BIKF Keflavikurflugvollur Observations ', '00Z 26 Feb 1983']

x = datetime.datetime.strptime(splitted_string[1], "%fZ %d %b %Y").strftime("%f-%d-%m-%Y")
print(x)
```

hope this code helps you.

Comment: I didn't know `strptime` could understand `%fZ`, that's neat! The only issue I see here is that your code sample returns `000000-26-02-1983`, which is not exactly what was sought I think, but it is close enough to begin with!

Comment: you can use slicing like this too get your result `print(x[:2] + x[6:])`

Comment: or simplier: `print(x[4:])` ;)